# MySQL Selecting from multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL I am trying to pull ALL `people` who's `company_id` matches `3` and also compare whether that `person` exists in the `favourites` table.

What I have noticed is that if a person has no `job_id` then they are not output by the below query.

The below query outputs 1 row, but in the `people` table there are 3 rows that match the `company_id` of `3`

```
                SELECT *,
                           j.company_id as companyid,
                           f.id IS NOT NULL AS jid,
                           p.id as pid,
                           f.id AS fave_id,
                           f.id IS NOT NULL AS fave
                      FROM people p  
                INNER JOIN job j 
                        ON p.job_id = j.id
                 LEFT JOIN favourites f
                        ON f.people_id=p.id
                       AND f.user_id = 12
                     WHERE p.company_id = 3
                  ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fd799)

Any help is appreciated to get the query to output all rows that match and also check the `favourites` table.

Comment: you are doing an inner join on job by the job_id but don't have matching values on the person table and by matching values i mean there is a blank empty string for one row you want to see with the ON condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a left join on job, it will show people that have no job_id. I have updated the fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fd799/10/0).

```
SELECT
    p.*,
    j.company_id as companyid,        
    f.id IS NOT NULL AS jid,
    p.id as pid,
    f.id AS fave_id,
    f.id IS NOT NULL AS fave
FROM people p  
LEFT JOIN job j 
       ON j.id = p.job_id
LEFT JOIN favourites f 
       ON f.people_id=p.id
      AND f.user_id = 12
WHERE p.company_id = 3
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

Comment: There were some invalid dates in the data. I have updated the schema, see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fd799/10/0

Answer (score 1):

You should change your INNER JOIN for the job table to a LEFT OUTER JOIN so they're selected regardless of whether or not they exist in the job table.

Comment: LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN are synonymous... but thats not the issue here.

Comment: The user's example used an INNER JOIN, which is what I suggested should be changed to a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: No i understand that.. if you look at the data the left join wouldn't make much a difference unless you specify NOT NULL in the select like the other answer... because there is a null value for the job_id and an empty string for the job_id in the favorites table